# :last-child property not applied to element

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation layed out as follows:

```
<div id=treeLevelContainer_0>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 5</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 6</a></div>
     <div class=treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 7</a></div>
</div>
```

And for each of these I have the following CSS:

```
.treeLevel_0
{
    width:98%;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    background:#FFF url(/Images/nav-divider.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
    text-align:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:5px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

However for the last one I don't want to have the background so I'm using the `:last-child` property:

```
#treeLevelContainer_0 .treeLevel_0:last-child
{
    background:none;
}
```

Yet for reason the `:last-child` is not being applied at all. Any ideas at all because I'm sure this is the way I've done this in the past?

Comment: `<div></treeLevel_0><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: I'm surprised this malformed HTML actually shows up on the page...

Comment: That's a typo on Stack overflow, I typed the code instead of copying and pasting - corrected now

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kD8mj/

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://jsfiddle.net/Shf8B/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/P9Cvc/

```
<div id=treeLevelContainer_0>
<div><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 5</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 6</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Link 7</a></div>
</div>

#treeLevelContainer_0 div
{
    width:98%;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    background:red;
    text-align:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:5px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#treeLevelContainer_0 div:last-child
{
    background:none;
}
```

this is solution ...btw it is better to do it with jQuery coz crosbroswer compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each of these malformatted lines as follows:

```
<div class="treeLevel_0"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
```

This should work.
Also, don't forget to put all IDs or classes within quotation marks (see your first line)

Comment: Thanks but that was a typo from when I was writing the question, corrected it now. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

```
#treeLevelContainer_0 .treeLevel_0:last-child{background-image:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same problem, background is still there